# textContent and removing \r\n?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am getting the content of a div using `getElementById` function, but inside the div there are some text formatting like `font, p, b ...`, so when i use `myvar.textContent`, i do get all the text but not exactly the way i need it ... I mean, instead of getting something like paragraphs, i get the lines separated :

```
*************************************
*************************************
*************.
```

I get :

```
******
 ***************
***********************
```

is there a way in javascript to remove the \r\n and still make a difference between two paragraphs, knowing that between two paragraphs there are 3 to 4 \r\n?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

What i am trying to do is to read body of an email in Gmail

what should look like :

*Dans la perspective de consolider sa relation avec les lauréats et étudiants, eHECT vous propose deparrainer un membre de votre famille souhaitant poursuivre ses études au sein de notre établissement.

Pour plus de détail et inscription allez sur ...*

I do get

Dans la perspective de consolider sa relation

avec les lauréats et étudiants,

eHECT vous propose deparrainer un membre de votre

famille souhaitant poursuivre ses études au sein de notre établissement.

Pour plus de détail et inscription allez sur ...

Comment: Would you mind giving us an example input, output of textContent, and desired output in addition to what you've already said?

Comment: Could you provide *real* inputs/outputs, and explicitly write the `\n` where they actually are? It's quite hard to understand as is.

Comment: ok sorry, i will edit now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get clear text divided into paragraphs, you need to get content with html tags (this is only way to reach information about paragraphs) and then remove unwanted tags like  `<b>`, `<font>`.

Comment: Of course the matter depends on source text. If it is divided into paragraphs by <p> tag - you should use it to separate text into paragraphs and then cleanse text from other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
/\r?\n((?!\r?\n)|(?=\r?\n\r?\n\r?\n))/g
```

[JavaScript demo here (check the console).](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/NyvYD/)

Comment: Did you get to try this one out?